# How to drag and drop a div inside another div and make that the whole element follow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Trying to use jqueryUI. I have a list with components that i want to drop inside a gridsystem. Like a desiger thing.
I have a div that has

```
$( "#Component1" ).draggable();
```

And I drop the div above in this div:

```
$( "#GridDiv" ).droppable({
    accept: "#component1"
});
```

The result I want is, when I drop the `component1` div insde the `GridDiv`

```
<div id="#GridDiv">
   <div id="#Component1"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a method for this ? i cant find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the element by yourself after [drop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop):

```
$( "#GridDiv" ).droppable({
    accept: "#Component1",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
       var droppable = $(this);
       var draggable = ui.draggable;
       // Move draggable into droppable
       draggable.appendTo(droppable);
    }
});
```

PS: You don't need to use # in the ID field:

```
<div id="GridDiv">
   <div id="Component1"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/7791/)

Comment: Dosent work, i was into similar thing. droppable.append(draggable.remove()); this ? .remove ? is the problem their maybe ? cause my div dosent get nestled :(

Comment: Fixed. Check the answer now! You also got a problem with your accept property `#component1` must be `#Component1`.

Answer (score 0):

As there is a issue with the styling of the dragged element while appending to another div (see [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7220) for further information), here is another approach for you:

```
$('#GridDiv').droppable({
    accept: "#Component1",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        var offset = draggable.offset();
        draggable.appendTo( this ).offset( offset );
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3uhsox1v/1/)

The following demo is slightly different: it removes the original dragged element, so the dragging functionality gets lost:

```
$('#GridDiv').droppable({
    accept: "#Component1",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        var offset = draggable.offset();
        draggable.remove().appendTo( this ).offset( offset );
    }
});
```

[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/mvmcL025/1/)

For resizing the draggable after it is dropped you can use:

```
draggable.resizable();
```

[Demo 3](https://jsfiddle.net/gfpk4oyd/)

**Reference**

[.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

[.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

[.droppable() - drop-option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: @user3510507 have you corrected your ID's as @nanndoj pointed out, `<div id="#GridDiv">` should only be `<div id="GridDiv">`. same with your other div ...

Comment: well i printed a div with php and it dosent work. now i make the div in the html doc then it works...

Comment: Do u know how i can move the Component agian when it is inside the GRID ? and resize it ?

Answer (score 0):

The above all are not a correct and exact answer because the all the outputs are placed top of the window, eg, the object placed in top:0px and left:0px position.

Try below

```
var droppable = $(this);
var draggable = ui.draggable;
ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' });
```